# Bizzare behavior from C program:: Kernighan & Ritchie exercise 2-3

Tags: c

all.

I've written a program as a solution to Kernighan & Ritchie's exercise 2-3, and its behaviour during testing is (IMHO) wildly unintuitive.

The problem spec says to write a program that converts hex values to their decimal equivalent.  The code I've written works fine for smaller hex values, but for larger hex values things get a little... odd.  For example, if I input **0x1234** the decimal value **4660** pops out on the other end, which happens to be the correct output (the code also works for letters, i.e. **0x1FC** -> **508**).  If, on the other hand, I were to input a large hex value, say as a specific example **0x123456789ABCDEF**, I *should* get **81985529216486895**, though instead I get **81985529216486896** (off by one digit!).

The error in conversion is inconsistent, sometimes with the decimal value being too high and other times too low. Generally, much larger hex values result in more incorrect place values in the decimal output.

Here's my program in its entirety:

```
/*Kernighan & Ritchie's Exercise 2-3

Write a function 'htoi' which converts a string of hexadecimal digits (including an 
optional 0x or 0X) into its equivalent integer value.
*/
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXLINE 1000 //defines maximum size of a hex input

//FUNCTION DEFINITIONS
signed int htoi(char c); //converts a single hex digit to its decimal value

//BEGIN PROGRAM////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
main()
{
   int i = 0; //counts the length of 'hex' at input
   char c; //character buffer
   char hex[MAXLINE]; //string from input
   int len = 0; //the final value of 'i'
   signed int val; //the decimal value of a character stored in 'hex'
   double n = 0; //the decimal value of 'hex'

   while((c = getchar()) != '\n') //store a string of characters in 'hex'
   {
      hex[i] = c;
      ++i;
   }
   len = i;
   hex[i] = '\0'; //turn 'hex' into a string

   if((hex[0] == '0') && ((hex[1] == 'x') || (hex[1] == 'X'))) //ignore leading '0x'
   {
      for(i = 2; i < len; ++i)
      {
        val = htoi(hex[i]); //call 'htoi'
        if(val == -1 ) //test for a non-hex character
        {
            break;
        }
        n = 16.0 * n + (double)val; //calculate decimal value of hex from hex[0]->hex[i]
      }
   }
   else
   {
      for(i = 0; i < len; ++i)
      {
          val = htoi(hex[i]); //call 'htoi'
          if(val == -1) //test for non-hex character
          {
             break;
          }
          n = 16.0 * n + (double)val; //calc decimal value of hex for hex[0]->hex[i]
      }
   }

 if(val == -1)
 {
    printf("\n!!THE STRING FROM INPUT WAS NOT A HEX VALUE!!\n");
 }
 else
 {
    printf("\n%s converts to %.0f\n", hex, n);
 }

 return 0;
 }

 //FUNCTION DEFINITIONS OUTSIDE OF MAIN()///////////////////////////////////
 signed int htoi(char c)
 {
   signed int val = -1;

   if(c >= '0' && c <= '9')
     val = c - '0';

   else if(c == 'a' || c == 'A')
     val = 10;

   else if(c == 'b' || c == 'B')
     val = 11;

   else if(c == 'c' || c == 'C')
     val = 12;

   else if(c == 'd' || c == 'D')
     val = 13;

   else if(c == 'e' || c == 'E')
     val = 14;

   else if(c == 'f' || c == 'F')
     val = 15;

   else 
   {
     ;//'c' was a non-hex character, do nothing and return -1
   }

   return val;
 }
```

pastebin: http://pastebin.com/LJFfwSN5

Any ideas on *what* is going on here?

Comment: Floating point types can't represent every number exactly. http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: Instead of duplicating your loop with one case `for (i=0` and the other `for(i=2)`, set `i` in the if-else and then do the loop without the initial condition.

Comment: also `char c;` should be `int c;` so you can detect EOF (this is covered elsewhere in K&R)

Comment: @AndrewMedico you should probably post that as an answer

Comment: @AndrewMedico, If I understand you correctly, then this behaviour is essentially a rounding error?  This makes some sense as to why the smaller hex values convert correctly (negligible error), but the large ones show increasingly odd behaviour. How do programmers deal with these sorts of issues in real-world applications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably exceeding the precision with which `double` can store integers.

My suggestion would be to change your code to use `unsigned long long` for the result; and also add in a check for overflow here, e.g.:

```
unsigned long long n = 0; 
// ...

if ( n * 16 + val < n )  
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Number too big.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

n = n * 16 + val;
```

My less-than check works because when unsigned integer types overflow they wrap around to zero.

If you want to add more precision than `unsigned long long` then you will have to get into more advanced techniques (probably beyond the scope of Ch. 2 of K&R but once you've finished the book you could revisit).

---

NB. You also need to `#include <stdlib.h>` if you take my suggestion of `exit`; and don't forget to change `%.0f` to `%llu` in your final `printf`. Also, a safer way to get the input (which K&R covers) is:

```
int c;
while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF)
```

The first time I ran the code on ideone I got segfault, because I didn't put a newline on the end of the `stdin` so this loop kept on shoving EOF into `hex` until it buffer overflowed.

Comment: Okay, it makes sense that I would have exceeded the size of `double`s, but changing the result `n` to `unsigned long long` doesn't alter the result or make the program behave any better with larger hex values.

Comment: @OhNo_Segfault if you follow my suggestion then either you will get exactly the right answer, or it will abort with the "Number too big" error . It's not possible to do any better than this without major changes.

Comment: I wish you were right. Inputting `0x123456789ABCDEF` with `double n` doesn't trip the overflow error message (it's therefore unsurprising that `stderr` doesn't trip with `unsigned long long n`, either). The _same_ wrong answer keeps being generated in either case. Did you manage to get the right answer?

Comment: @OhNo_Segfault Yes, [see here](http://ideone.com/MUmRt2). Updated my post to mention some pitfalls

Comment: Huzzah! I worked! In my previous post I had included `<stdlib.h>` (because `gcc` complains about implicitly declaring `exit()` if you don't) merely implemented the type change from `double n` to `unsigned long long int` (and changed `%.0f` to `%llu`--more complaining from `gcc`), but what finally made it work was changing `char c` to `int c`. What's up with that? 0.o

Comment: @OhNo_Segfault `c` has to be able to represent every possible character, as well as `EOF`, therefore `char` is not big enough for the job!  You should see this in other examples in the same book where they use `EOF`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic example of floating point inaccuracy.

Unlike most of the examples of floating point errors you'll see, this is clearly not about non-binary fractions or very small numbers; in this case, the floating point representation is approximating very *big* numbers, with the accuracy decreasing the higher you go. The principle is the same as writing "1.6e10" to mean "approximately 16000000000" (I think I counted the zeros right there!), when the actual number might be 16000000001.

You actually run out of accuracy sooner than with an integer of the same size because only part of the width of a floating point variable can be used to represent a whole number.

Comment: To wit: It's a rounding error? How do programmers deal with this sort of issue in real-world application? I mean, it seems infeasible that there wouldn't ever be a need to work with a high degree of precision on very large whole numbers that were larger than ULONG_MAX.

Comment: I think it's fair to say "with difficulty" - given a fixed width variable (which is what hardware is built to work with), there will always be some limit on the size of number you can accurately represent. Libraries exist which use variable width variables, such as Binary Coded Decimal (work with a string of digits) or the GNU Multiple Precision library, which I think uses a kind of array of integers with a lot of magic under the hood to make the maths work. In both cases, you trade efficiency of calculation for a (theoretically) unlimited range.